# How to do proguard for my library (AAR)

Tags: android, minify, android-proguard, aar

I am developing one android library for that i want enable the progurad.

**First thing i did is:**

I have enabled the minification for my library

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

After this, I have generated the AAR file with minification. And then i used the AAR file to my testing app to check whether my library classes were available. But classes were not there, Because the pro guard removed all my classes from library as it was not used.

**Second thing i did is:**

```
-keep public interface com.example.client.** { *; }
```

I have added the above thing to my proguard-rules.pro. Now i can able to see all my classes with proguard applying the same class, function, variable names. (In mapping file i could see the same name getting applied)

I don't know the exact way to apply the proguard to generate the obfuscated AAR.

Is there any guideline to generate AAR with the minification/

Or in my case what is fix to generate AAR with the class available?

I am struggling for a long time... Could someone please try to help me!!!